# Facebook Canvas App: SSL connection error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I'm trying to make a Facebook canvas app, eventually to be hosted on Heroku, but right now it's on localhost.  I can sign in to my app on local host with Facebook, but when I try to visit the app (which is just an html page right now) on Facebook, I get this SSL error.

```
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

This is how I set up the app on Facebook. can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? I understand that I should be able to see the app on Facebook when I visit the app page. 
[image: This is how I set up the App on Facebook]

Note, it's in Sandbox mode, if that makes a difference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have ssl in your localhost.

Desactive Secure browsing in your personal account to see your app
Account Settings > Security > Secure browsing

Comment: Or: Implement SSL on your test server. For example OpenSSL under Apache is not to hard to set up with a self-signed certificate … have your browser accept this certificate once, and you’re good to go testing using HTTPS as well.

Comment: Life saver, facebook knows well how to hide this info.. +1